# Generators of a finite additive cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $C$ be an abelian additive group and write e for a generator of $C$. The elements of $C$ are then $0,e,2e,3e,\dots,(n-1)e$.  If $C$ is finite, prove that the element $ke$ is another generator of $C$ if and only if $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Can you argue the 'if' and/or the 'only if' part?

Comment: I do not believe so.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one direction: Let $\gcd(k,n) = 1 $ then there exist $i, j \in \mathbb Z$ such that $1 = ik + jn$. If $me$ is an arbitrary element in $C$, $m \in \mathbb Z$, then $me = m(ik + in) e = mik e + min e = mike = (mi)ke$.

The statement is a actually a direct consequence of the following theorem:

Let $a$ be an element of order $n$ and let $k$ be a positive integer. Then $| a^k|  = n / \gcd(n,k)$.

Comment: See for example [Gallian](http://books.google.ch/books/about/Contemporary_Abstract_Algebra.html?id=CnH3mlOKpsMC&redir_esc=y), 7th Edition, page 75, Theorem 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose gcd$(n, k) = 1$.
Supose $mke = 0$ for an integer $m$.
Then $n|mk$.
Since gcd$(n, k) = 1$, $n|m$.
Hence the order of $ke$ is $n$.

Conversely suppose $d =$ gcd$(n, k) \ne 1$.
Let $k' = \frac{k}{d}, n' = \frac{n}{d}$.
Then $n'ke = n'dk'e = nk'e = 0$.
Since $n' < n, ke$ is not a generator.

Comment: Can you elaborate why from $mke = 0 $, $n | mk$ follows?